# flutter web - manually changing width between two sizedbox in browser by cursor

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How can I manually change width of two sizedbox in browser by cursor, without resizing browser's window? My "start screen" is 50/50, and then I want to change it my cursor dynamically e.g. 32/68 or 71/29.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: my solution: it works :) https://pub.dev/packages/multi_split_view

Answer (score 3):

If you need to change the size of widgets within the window, you could do that by listening to the pointer events, or simply using the `GestureDetector` widget. Then you have to modify the size based on the offset applied by the given gesture. For instance, if you're changing the size horizontally with a draghandle, then you'd do something like this:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
    final delta = details.delta.dx;
    // right is positive and left is negative
    if (delta.isNegative) {
      // reduce the size of the left size
      // and increase the right one.
    } else {
      // reduce the size of the right size
      // and increase the left one.
    }
  },
  child: Container(
    height: dragHandleSize,
    width: dragHandleSize,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
),
```

I made a simple example on DartPad with a fully runnable code sample that you can view here: [Widget Resizing](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c8831a85512a80bd07c012ae969e7cc4)

This is how it would look like:

[image: Window Resizing Example]

Comment: Great Job, Thank You. :)